# Why does my DIY printer start printing in air?

Tags: z-axis, bed-leveling, simplify3d, z-probe, pronterface

I've built a DIY 3D printer similar to Prusa i3. It does *homing* and *bed leveling* very well with a PNP Lj12a3_4_Z_BY sensor using `G28` and `G29`.

[image: Lj12a3_4_Z_BY]

However, when I push the print button on Pronterface or Simplify3D, Z axis goes up about 20mm and starts printing in air. I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the cad model was imported from Solidworks into Simplify3D. Push "Center and Arrange" button to place the model in the middle of the Heat Bed. There might be a gap between the object and bed level that is hard to see.